# Heroku Public Assets are Stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Assets on Heroku are not updating with new code/assets/css.

I tried heroku rake assets:clean. I right clicked an image. I can see the code still has the old compiled asset hash in the public dir.

I even tried bumping the asset version.

`Rails.application.config.assets.version = '2.0'`

I am on Rails 5. This below line is in the Rails default production config. I didn't know apache handled serving static assets. Is that something new?

It also seems like Heroku is getting assets from somewhere else. Another server? If I delete the entire public dir right on the server, it still serves the assets on the website.

Comment

## Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since

## Apache or NGINX already handles this.

`config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing this output when you push to Heroku?

`-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally`

That means it is still seeing a manifest file. Delete the public/assets directory to remove it with `rake assets:clobber`. Then you need to add these changes and then push to Heroku.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize my local assets had gotten compiled and were being pushed up to Heroku. Saved the day!.